# Почему Cursor возвращает null IntentService Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

При создании уведомления я получаю значение Uri такого формата

> content://com.example.myappv2/notes/2

после чего пытаюсь получить значение курсора чтобы добавить описание из строки в БД к моему уведомлению, но cursor возвращает null, но уведомление срабатывает в указанное время, но пустое, что я делаю не так? 
Ниже представлен весь код класса? буду признателен за любые ответы

```
public class ReminderAlarmService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = ReminderAlarmService.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
public String description;
PendingIntent operation;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
static final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";


// Это намерение с глубокими ссылками, для которого требуется стек задач
public static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Intent action = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);


    action.setData(uri);

    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, action, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}

public ReminderAlarmService() {
    super(TAG);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

    // Отображение уведомления для просмотра деталей задачи
    Intent action = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    action.setData(uri);
    operation = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Получить описание задачи
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

   try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            description = ConstantsDB.getColumnString(cursor, ConstantsDB.KEY_NAME);

        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "discription " + uri );

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(description)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic1)
            .setContentIntent(operation)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

}

Comment: Вы что-то совсем не то делаете. Uri, Intent, ContentResolver -- как-то вы все это замешали что ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать уведомления к своим заметкам, часть кода взял отсюда https://github.com/delaroy/AlarmReminder/tree/NotificationTitleSound сделал свой контент провайдер и привел Uri в нормальный вид, но курсор так же возвращает null хотя должен возвращать значение ячейки из БД